# Can anyone suggest a good Mass Duplicate Leads Merge Free tool?

Tags: leads, lead-conversion, duplicate-management

what are the best Free tool for lead find duplicates and merge? Default lead merge only allows three records to merge. I need to merge more than one records
 We have figured out 1500+ leads which have duplicates and we want to merge. How to Mass Merge them?

Answer (score 5):

This is probably one of those situations where you have a tradeoff between cost and time.

When I (well, me and my intern) needed to sort through roughly 30,000 `Contact` records to 'deduplicate' and 'merge' when my org implemented the feature to allow `Contacts` to be related to more than one `Account`, we used Microsoft Excel to handle the bulk of the work.

The workflow looked something like this:

1. Export all `Contact` records using the Apex Data Loader
2. Open the resulting .csv file in Excel
3. Sort the `Contacts` by multiple columns (last name, first name, email, Account Name, in that order)
4. Add a new column to hold a formula that checks if the last name, first name, etc... of the current column matches the one above it. If so, mark as duplicate, else, mark as unique
5. Add more new columns to hold formulas that 'merge' fields. For us, we mostly were looking at the column between the current row, and the one above. If the current row was a 'duplicate', and the same column for the row above was blank, have the row above take the value from the row below
6. Add a filter to the 'duplicate' formula column so we only display the unique rows
7. Select all rows, copy, then paste special (only filtered rows) into a new table
8. Save the new table (containing only the unique records, with their 'rolled-up-values) as a csv file
9. Fire up the Data Loader again, and update the records in the csv file from step 8 (after mapping the 'roll-up' formula cells to their respective actual fields)
10. Via anonymous apex, query for all records that were not just updated, and delete them

As I recall, step 5 was one of the harder ones to pull off. I don't recall exactly how we did it, but it is possible.

If you have more experience with Apex than my intern had, there's probably an easier way to do this using anonymous apex. At any rate though, setting this up does take a considerable amount of time. You'll need to balance that against your aversion to paid solutions.

Answer (score 3):

There are no free tools apart from the one built into Salesforce. Start with that one. Set up your Duplicate Rules to "Report", not Alert or Block.,

From the help:

> If you’re saving multiple records at the same time and your duplicate rules are set to Block or Alert, records within the same save aren’t compared to each other; they are only compared with records already in Salesforce. This behavior doesn't affect the Report action, and duplicate record sets include records that match other records in the same save.

Set up your duplicate rules then create a field on the Lead object named Update - Checkbox field.

Now via some form of data loader, run a mass update to set Update to True - this will force all Leads to be duplicated checked. Run your Duplicate report to see the results.

This still requires manual merging then. I do find Lightning nicer for merging.

Comment: Duplicate reports & duplicate jobs are only available for Performance and Unlimited Editions, as of Summer '19 at least :/

Answer (score 0):

DemandTools by CRM Fusion, hands down. They have a few modules that handle de-duplication, can merge multiple records into one, and even allow scenarios to be built letting you define the master records in each of your duplicate groups. I highly recommend checking that out.

Comment: any free tool ? @danG

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't look like DemandTools allows for files outside of Salesforce. You can only dedupe within Salesforce (prod or sandbox environments)