# Mass Finding Duplicate Leads in Salesforce

Tags: leads, duplicate-management, duplicate-value, findduplicates

Sales Rep has Uploaded leads into salesforce by adding them as campaign members. The leads under campaign members have many duplicates,
can anyone suggest a method or a process to **find out Mass duplicate leads**.

Thank You

Comment: This link might help you
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/185404/can-anyone-suggest-a-good-mass-duplicate-leads-merge-free-tool

Comment: Try any one of this appexchange product. https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxSearchKeywordResults?keywords=duplicate%20management

Comment: Can you clarify if you are trying to do a one-time cleanup or putting in place a recurring process for managing duplicates?